# Variation of the $\ln$ of the determinant of a matrix $M$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, variational-calculus

Consider, for any matrix $M$, the variation of $\ln |\det M|$ induced by a variation of $M$'s elements. We should get the following:

$$
\delta \ln |\det M| = \ln |\det(M + \delta M)| - \ln|\det M|
$$

However, when I try to evaluate the lhs of the equation, I use the variation of the logarithm function as:
$$
\delta \ln |\det M| = \frac{\delta |\det M|}{|\det M|}.
$$

Why is my deduction not correct? How do I get to the proposed solution?

Comment: Might this be better for [math.se]?

Comment: Since I encountered this in a physics book, I thought it'd be more appropriate to ask it here.

Comment: Yes but the problem is purely mathematical in nature and there isn't anything physical driving the question itself.

Comment: [Due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula).

Answer (score 2):

Start from
$$
\ln ({\rm det} M)= {\rm tr} (\ln M),
$$
so
$$
\delta\{\ln ({\rm det} M)\}= \delta \{{\rm tr} (\ln M)\}= {\rm tr}\{ M^{-1} \delta M\}.
$$